# Correct check JSON with arrays in Codecept

Tags: php, json, rest, codeception

Little issue, how to correct check JSON, recieved with GET by codeception.

Here it come..

```
{
   "brands":[
      {
         "letter":"b",
         "list":[
            {
               "text_ident":"brand1",
               "title":"brand1",
               "shortDescription":"brand1brand1"
            },
            {
               "text_ident":"brand2",
               "title":"brand2",
               "shortDescription":"brand2brand2"
            },
            {
               "text_ident":"brand3",
               "title":"brand3",
               "shortDescription":"brand3brand3"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "letter":"v",
         "list":[
            {
               "text_ident":"vrand3",
               "title":"vrand3",
               "shortDescription":"vrand3vrand3"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

And here is the BrandsMenuCept.php test
I start it with...

```
$fix = new app\tests\api\v1\fixtures\BrandsFixture();
$fix->load();

$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('test GET v1/brands/menu');

$I->sendGet('http://example.com/v1/brands/menu');
$I->seeResponseCodeIs('200');
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath('$.brands');
 ...
```

And what i should write after, how to check multiple arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:
First json_decode the response with true parameter like this

```
$responsearr=json_decode($json, true);
```

Then you can check the count of the array like this:

```
if(count($responsearr)>0){
 //logic follows here...
}else{
 //invalid json message comes here
}
```